# Paid auto registration tax twice in 2017, can both payments be deducted?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, car

The tax on this one vehicle is due January but has a 30 day grace period. Bill usually arrives in early Dec. I paid the tax in Feb 2017, and then again in Dec 2017.

Can I tell TurboTax that I paid twice as much the tax? (I know that it will help me figure out the part that is actually deductible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You received a bill in 2017 and you paid it. So yes it can be used include in your 2017 itemized deductions.

Before the tax law changes for 2018 it was standard advice to bunch tax bills if you could. If you were close to the standard deduction then by essentially paying twice one year and zero times the next year, you could make sure that 1/2 the years you could itemize, instead of just being under the limit every year.

In December 2017 many people were scrambling to pay property and car taxes before the end of the year. The information from the IRS was that if you had a bill in your hand in 2017, then you could pay it in 2017 and use it on the tax forms you will file in April 2018.

Tell turbo tax that how much you paid and when. You can actually include details in the box so that you can provide the dates and the amounts instead of just one combined number.